# multi colored rel or line plot in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Im the dataframe below, I have unique `compIds` which can have multiple `capei` and multiple `date`. This is primarily a time series dataset.

```
    date     capei     compId
0   200401  25.123777   31946.0
1   200401  15.844910   29586.0
2   200401  20.524131   32507.0
3   200401  15.844910   29586.0
4   200401  15.844910   29586.0
... ... ... ...
73226   202011  9.372320    2817.0
73227   202011  9.372320    2817.0
73228   202011  22.334842   28581.0
73229   202011  10.761727   31946.0
73230   202011  30.205348   15029.0
```

With the following visualization code, I get the plot but the color of the line plots are not different. I wanted different colors.

```
import seaborn as sns

a4_dims = (15, 5)

sns.set_palette("vlag")


**plot**
sns.set_style('ticks')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

fig.set_size_inches(11.7, 8.27)

sns.relplot(x="date", ax=ax, y="capei",   style='compId', kind='line',data=fDf, palette=sns.color_palette("Spectral", as_cmap=True) )
```

It generates image like this

[image]

However I am expecting plot as like

[image]

The compId in the picture generated figure 1 can be Month equivalent in figure 2.
Figure 2 is a screenshot from [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html).

**How would be able to have different colors for compId in the Figure 1.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should reformat your dataframe:

- convert `'date'` from `str` to `datetime`:

  ```
  fDf['date'] = pd.to_datetime(fDf['date'], format='%Y%m')
  ```
- convert `'compId'` from `float` to `str` in order to be used as a categorical axis<sup>(1)</sup>:

  ```
  fDf['compId'] = fDf['compId'].apply(str)
  ```

Now you can pass `'compId'` to [**`seaborn.relplot`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) as `hue` and/or `style` parameter, depending on your preferencies.

### Complete Code

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fDf = pd.read_csv(r'data/data.csv')
fDf['date'] = pd.to_datetime(fDf['date'], format='%Y%m')
fDf['compId'] = fDf['compId'].apply(str)


sns.set_palette("vlag")
sns.set_style('ticks')

sns.relplot(x="date", y="capei", style='compId', hue='compId', kind='line',data=fDf, estimator=None)

plt.show()
```

[image]

(plot drawn with a fake-dataframe)

---

This passage may or may not be necessary; given the context I suggest it is.
If you keep `compId` as numerical type, then the `hue` in the plot will be proportional to `'compId'`value. This means `0.4` will have a color very different from `31946.0`; but `31946.0` and `32507.0` will be practically indistinguishable by color.
If you convert `compId` to `str`, then the `hue` won't depent of `compId` numerical value, so the colors will be *equally* spaced among categories.

| `fDf['compId']` as it is | `fDf['compId'].apply(str)` |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |